# React.js CRUD best practices and component hierarchy?

Tags: reactjs, components, crud, hierarchy

I made a little CRUD for a list of items with React and a Spring Boot backend with REST API. I started with a stateful App.jsx component, that had the logic to make a GET call in order to fetch all the items. The items were fetched into a stateless component called ListItems, and each item on the list was another component called Item. So, the hierarchy was something like this:

```
App (renders ListItems) -> ListItems (stateless, renders many Items) -> Item (stateless)
```

Then I tried to use React Router. I added the routes  in App and the links  in ListItems, in order to click the item in the list and go to its details in the future.

But then things started to become messy. I needed a DELETE, POST and PUT method, which involved two forms: One to create a new item, and another one to edit it. I created a new component with the details of a certain item, called ItemDetails. The idea was to show the list of items with a url to their details page (e.g. localhost/items/50), and in there, I would show a button to edit that item, or delete. That's where I started to get lost. I ended up making the item details page a stateful component and it all crumbled apart. I don't know which component(s) should be stateful in order to make a webpage like that. Also, the forms needed to be updated manually with a method in order to be able to write in them. I ended up with a lot of stateful components just to make it work, but I'm certain that there's a much better way to aproach this. Could you give me some insight on the structure of a project like that?

**tl;dr**: I need help with the structure and 'hierarchy' of a CRUD, consisting of a page with a list of items that you can click and go to another page with that item's details and the option to edit and delete it. Also, in the list of items, I need a link to another view where I can create a new item. Which components should be stateful? Every example I've seen is very simple and they don't approach a very basic problem like this. They use mock data, mock methods, and end up with a mock structure that doesn't work in real scenarios.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about things being stateful or stateless. Think in terms of API (i.e. `props`) and state (well... `state`).

Here's how I'd proceed: I'd create an ItemDetails component that can either be in `edit` or in `create` mode. It'll receive an Item as a prop (for both edition and creation) and display a form with all the stuff you want to edit. When the form changes, a new Item will be stored in the ItemDetails' state and used to render. The ItemDetail is in charge of displaying the save/delete buttons, whatever happens upon clicking on those can either be dealt with in the ItemDetails component or through appropriate props passed to it.

This approach works well with immutable objects.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the fact that ItemDetails receives an item as prop for creation, since I don't actually have an item to create before the creation process itself. So I'd only have a set of attributes in mind which I'll insert in a form to create the item.  Now that you mention what happens after you save/delete, that's another issue I'm having (I started on React like three days ago). I don't know how to implement an "update list on add/remove". Could you write the skeleton of the idea you have in mind please? Just the relation between components and stuff like that. Thanks.